# custom libindicator icon is not displayed

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk

I want to change the status icon of my own little reminder program. Currently I am using **GTK.StatusIcon** but I want to use a **ApplicationIndicator.**

Therefore I created an own Icon and moved it to:

```
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/status/22
```

It is named indicator-notify.svg

Heres the code for the icon.

```
ind = appindicator.Indicator ("notify",
                          "indicator-notify",
                          appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
ind.set_status (appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
```

This Icon is not displayed. Although every other icon from this folder is.

What did I miss? Is there maybe the need to "register" the icon in GTK ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to register it, but your icon cache needs to be updated after installing new icons. You can do this via `gtk-update-icon-cache` (see http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-update-icon-cache.html)